# Merge all data frame into a single file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of data frames which looks like this:

df1

| Seller | Vaule | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hari | 2 | Jan-02 |
| Om | 12 | Jan-02 |
| Cat | 0 | Jan-02 |
| Mat | 14 | Jan-02 |
| John | 0 | Jan-02 |
| Messi | 1 | Jan-02 |
| John | 0 | Jan-02 |
| Ronaldo | 7 | Jan-02 |

Df2

| Seller | Vaule | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hari | 0 | Jan-03 |
| Om | 14 | Jan-03 |
| Cat | NA | Jan-03 |
| Mat | 14 | Jan-03 |
| Ron | 0 | Jan-03 |
| Messi | 10 | Jan-03 |
| John | 0 | Jan-03 |
| Ronaldo | 17 | Jan-03 |

Like that I have many data frames

Merge all into single file and keep only the seller whose latest values are all greater than 0.

Final DF would be like -

| Seller | Vaule_jan02 | Vaule_jan03 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Om | 12 | 14 |
| Mat | 14 | 14 |
| Messi | 1 | 10 |
| Ronaldo | 7 | 17 |

Note - In df1 Hari's value was greater than 0 but in df2 it's value is 0 so we have not included in our final DF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the DataFrames in the desired order, then use a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), getting the last value per Seller and post-filter using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) and [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to keep the rows with only positive values:

```
(pd.concat([df1, df2])
   # sort by Month-year (use %b-%d if Month-day)
   .sort_values(by='Date', key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%b-%y'))
    # reshape to wide form, keeping only the last value
   .pivot_table(index='Seller', columns='Date', values='Vaule', aggfunc='last')
    # keep only rows with all positive values
   .loc[lambda d: d.gt(0).all(axis=1)]
   .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
    Seller  Jan-02  Jan-03
0      Mat    14.0    14.0
1    Messi     1.0    10.0
2       Om    12.0    14.0
3  Ronaldo     7.0    17.0
```

###### intermediate before the `loc` filtering step:

```
Date     Jan-02  Jan-03
Seller                 
Cat         0.0     NaN
Hari        2.0     0.0
John        0.0     0.0
Mat        14.0    14.0  # those rows only
Messi       1.0    10.0  # have positive values
Om         12.0    14.0  # keep them
Ron         NaN     0.0
Ronaldo     7.0    17.0  #
```

Comment: Thanks mozway for your effort. Your solution is perfect. I have one small request. Since I have many files so the output columns of dates are not in order. Can you please make all the columns in order to dates?

Comment: Like Jan-02, Jan-03, Jan-04, and so on. Currently is coming up like Jan-02, Jan-03, Dec-03

Comment: Add `.sort_values(by='Date', key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%b-%y'))` after the `concat` or `%b-%d` depending on whether `03` is the year or day

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
(pd.concat([df1, df2])
 .drop_duplicates('Seller',keep='last')
 .loc[lambda x: x['Vaule'].ne(0)]
 .dropna())
```

Output:

```
    Seller  Value    Date
1       Om   12.0  Jan-02
3      Mat   14.0  Jan-02
5    Messi   10.0  Jan-02
7  Ronaldo    7.0  Jan-02
```

---

To answer the requirement:

```
(pd.concat([df1, df2])
 .drop_duplicates('Seller',keep='last')
 .loc[lambda x: x['Vaule'].ne(0)]
 .dropna()
 .merge(df1, on='Seller', suffixes=('_jan03', '_jan02'))
 .loc[:, ['Seller', 'Vaule_jan02', 'Vaule_jan03']])
```

Output:

```
    Seller  Value_jan02  Value_jan03
0       Om           12         14.0
1      Mat           14         14.0
2    Messi            1         10.0
3  Ronaldo            7         17.0
```

---

A more general approach, which is based on `reduce` combined with `merge`:

```
from functools import reduce

list_df = [df1, df2]

(reduce(lambda x, y:  
    pd.merge(x, y, on='Seller', suffixes=['', f"_{y['Date'][0]}"]), list_df)
 .rename({'Value': f"Value_{df1['Date'][0]}"}, axis=1)
 .loc[lambda x: x.iloc[:,-2].gt(0), lambda x: ~x.columns.str.startswith('Date')])
```

Comment: I came later than @mozway :-), but above there is another possibility.

Comment: @PaulS I think your `merge` approach is not easy to generalize to an arbitrary number of dataframes (then a `concat` with 'Seller' as index might be better suited), but I have to say I always like your way to see things from a different perspective, very refreshing :)

Comment: Thanks, @mozway! That is true that the `merge` approach does not generalize well. But if I meanwhile find a better way, I will come back here.

Comment: @PaulS I'd do: `pd.concat([d.drop_duplicates('Seller', keep=False).set_index('Seller')['Vaule'].rename(d['Date'].iloc[0]) for d in [df1, df2]], axis=1).loc[lambda d: d.gt(0).all(axis=1)]`

Comment: Great an inspiring solution, @mozway! Thanks!

Comment: By using `reduce`, we can generalized the `merge` solution, @mozway! Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with remove `seller`s if Values are less like `0`, remove duplicates and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, Df2])

df = (df[~df['Seller'].isin(df.loc[df['Vaule'].le(0), 'Seller'])]
        .drop_duplicates()
        .groupby('Seller', as_index=False)['Vaule']
        .sum()
        )
print (df)
    Seller  Vaule
0      Mat   14.0
1    Messi   10.0
2       Om   12.0
3  Ronaldo    7.0
```